# Twiddle Operation Invocation

Tags: jboss, twiddle

Anyone know where Twiddle's real documentation is? Nothing is appearing online for how to construct objects in the command line and then pass them as a parameter to an MBean operation invocation. Not sure why JBoss released software without documentation.

I can invoke MBean operations with string parameters, but any other type of object besides string seems to be undocumented.

Thanks!